# Prove if $A'=UAU^{+}$ then ${A'}^{+}=UA^{+}U^{+}$

Tags: operator-theory

> *Question:* Prove that  $$A'=UAU^{+}  \implies   {A'}^{+}=UA^{+}U^{+}$$

I figure up that I have to use the Unitary operator's relation

$$UU^{+}=U^{+}U=1$$

But I cannot find the trick.

I really appreciate if someone can help me.

Comment: What are A and U?

Comment: You only need $$(AB)^\{dagger} = B^{\dagger} A^{\dagger}$$

Comment: they are operators, U is the unitary operator

Answer (score 0):

You'll need this property
$$\left( AB\right)^+ = B^+A^+$$
and note that
$$(A^+)^+=A$$
Actually, this has nothing to do with U being unitary.

The complete proof:
$$A'^+ = ( UAU^+)^+ = (U^+)^+(UA)^+=U(A^+U^+)=UA^+U^+$$

Comment: But I got that $A'^{+}=U^{+}A^{+}U$ instead $A'^{+}=UA^{+}U^{+}$

Comment: @Eliezer I've included complete proof.